# PHP error with a shortcode: "no suitable wrapper" for file_get_contents

Tags: php, shortcode, json

Why do I get the PHP warning "no suitable wrapper" for file_get_contents in this shortcode? It's probably more a PHP issue than WordPress.

The shortcode works fine and outputs in a page/post. But my error log is filling up with the warnings. I know PHP warnings are not serious, but I still want to fix the code that throws the warning.

```
// Wikipedia Last Edit Date

function wikipedia_article_date() {

$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Test_article&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&format=json";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$date = $data['query']['pages']['746140638']['revisions'][0]['timestamp'];

$date = new DateTime($date);
return $date->format('m-d-Y'); 
}

add_shortcode('article_date','wikipedia_article_date');
```

Comment: What is the value of your server's `allow_url_fopen` setting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551379/file-get-contents-error

Comment: It's enabled in php.ini, as is allow_url_include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTTP API:

```
$http = wp_remote_get( 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Test_article&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&format=json' );

if ( ! $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $http ) )
    return;

if ( ! $data = json_decode( $body, true ) )
    return;

$date = new DateTime( $data['query']['pages']['746140638']['revisions'][0]['timestamp'] );

return $date->format( 'm-d-Y' );
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great, with no need for allow_url_fopen or allow_url_include.